# How to load the slib library in chez scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, chez-scheme

How to load the slib library in chez scheme?

Or any other web server library for chez scheme?

On the manual of slim it says:

> 3. Configure the Scheme implementation(s) to locate the SLIB directory and implementation directories.
> 4. Arrange for each Scheme implementation to load its SLIB initialization file.
> 5. Build the SLIB catalog for each Scheme implementation.

I don't know how to do specially the steps 3 and 4.

This is what I get if I run "chez" in the document slib:

```
> (load "require.scm")
Exception: variable slib:features is not bound
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
> (load "chez.init")
> (require 'http)
Exception in call-with-output-file: failed for /usr/local/lib/chez/slibcat: no such file or directory
> (require 'http-cgi)
Exception in call-with-output-file: failed for /usr/local/lib/chez/slibcat: no such file or directory
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
> (load "http-cgi.scm")
Exception in call-with-output-file: failed for /usr/local/lib/chez/slibcat: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this error

```
Exception in call-with-output-file: failed for /usr/local/lib/chez/slibcat: no such file or directory"
```

as you didn't initiate SLib Catalog first
you can do this by running this first in repl:

```
(require 'new-catalog)
```

Comment: > (load "chez.init")
> (require 'new-catalog)
Exception in call-with-output-file: failed for /usr/local/lib/chez/slibcat: no such file or directory

Comment: you need to configure chez.init up to your system variables, srfi-96 can help understanding the required: https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-96/srfi-96.html

Comment: would you tell me how to configure the slib with chez scheme? thx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, obtain the zip file.

Then, as root:

- Create the directory `/usr/local/lib/chez`
- Copy the zip file into `/usr/local/lib`
- Unzip the zip file
- Start Chez

```lisp
(load "/usr/local/lib/slib/chez.init")
(require 'new-catalog)
```

As a normal user:

```lisp
(load "/usr/local/lib/slib/chez.init")
```